# Condition is always true since types 'string' and 'null' have no overlap

Tags: typescript, phpstorm

What does this PhpStorm warning/inspection mean?

> Condition is always true since types 'string' and 'null' have no overlap

[image: screenshot]

The code in question:

```js
function foo() {
    let input: string | null = prompt("test");
    if (input !== null) {
        console.log("not aborted");
    }
}
```

This only seems to happen in the `<script setup lang="ts">` section of a `.vue` file, not in a standalone `.ts` file.

My `tsconfig.json` has `strict` and `isolatedModules` set to `true`.

Comment: Generally, it means you tried to compare two types that don't make sense together. But I can't reproduce that error in this particular case. After filling in `api` and `load` with `any` stubs, the code compiles fine, with or without `--strict`. Do you happen to have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the error in this case? Because comparing a `string | null` to `null` makes perfect sense and compiles fine on my end.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I have replaced the code in the question with a standalone example without any dependencies. Sorry, should have done that from the beginning.

Comment: Also, I just noticed, this only seems to happen in the `<script setup lang="ts">` section of a `.vue` file, not in a standalone `.ts` file.

Comment: Right now this is irreproducible in my environment; you've got this tagged "phpstorm"; is that actually relevant?  Does it have to do with vue somehow?  Please consider [edit]ing the question to provide enough detail in the text to reproduce. Otherwise ‍♂️  (also, 
screenshots of IDEs are not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218))

Comment: @jcalz I think the phpstorm tag is relevant because it is a PhpStorm warning. At first I didn't think it had to do with Vue but I noticed now that it only happens in `.vue` files, see my edit. I have included all text and code from the screenshots also as text to make it searchable, but I think the screenshot is quite important to convey that it's a PhpStorm warning and not for example something that `tsc` outputs.

Comment: You should make that clear by writing it as plaintext in the question, and not relying on people looking at images of an IDE screenshot, which are inappropriate on Stack Overflow for the reasons in the linked meta doc above.

Comment: @jcalz Indeed I should at least mention it in the text instead of expecting people to look at the tags. Done.

Comment: Looks like input will NEVER be null. So prompt will certainly return an empty string if empty.

Comment: I failed to reproduce the issue (tried both `.vue` and `ts` files) in 2023.1.1. What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @lena I'm also on 2023.1.1. I'll see if I can put together a complete repro project,